# Refactoring jq with a variable key name?

Tags: function, key, refactoring, jq

Is there a way to refactor `jq` into functions?

**Prior to refactor:**

```
jq ' .them ."keyName" ' ./some.json
```

**After refactor:**

```
def getThese(x): .them .$x;
```

in **~/.jq**

and then call it with...

```
jq ' getThese("keyName") as $i | $i ' ./some.json
```

The above refactor does not appear to work (is there a way?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The abbreviation '.x.y' will not work if y is a variable. Use the syntax '.x | .[ y ]' instead.
2. 'E as $i| $i' can be written as 'E' in this case.
3. Your definition should be either:

```
def getThese(x): .them | .[x];
```

or with different semantics (and requiring a sufficiently recent version of jq):

```
def getThese($x): .them | .[$x];
```

4. One alternative would be to define `getThem` as:

```
def getThem(f): .them | f;
```

This would allow you to write: `getThem(.keyName)` for keys with unexceptional names.